# Is this grid fin piece a standard LEGO brick?

Tags: part-identification, customization

I'm trying to identify the circled part from this MoC, but I haven't been successful in doing so. On the one hand, the creator of this has called out two other parts in it (not shown here) as being modifications of existing bricks; but didn't say anything about the one I'm asking about, and the spacing in the grid looks about the same as in a LEGO fence piece which makes me think it might be a standard brick after all.

The original source for the MoC appears to be [this post on Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10111306763946261&set=pcb.831328153939104&type=3&theater). Not having an account there, I can't ask the designer directly.

[image]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I think that is

[Part# 30046 :
Window 1 x 2 x 2 2/3 Pane Lattice Diamond with Rounded Top](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=30046#T=C)

[image]

Comment: Holding off on accepting for the moment, but I think that's it.

Answer (score 25):

Looking at the pictures, I think Syberion has correctly identified the part.

Just want to cover the moment where you mention part modification may be required. I don't think there is a need for modifications, it should work with existing parts like this:

[image]

Additional parts are:

[Bar 1L with Clip Mechanical Claw](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/search.page?q=Bar%201L%20with%20Clip*#T=A)

[Plate, Round 1 x 1 with Open Stud](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=85861#T=C)

[Lever Small Base](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4592&idColor=0#T=C&C=0) taken from [Lever Small Base with Black Lever](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4592c02#T=C)

Comment: Thanks for that assembly guide.  It never would've occurred to me to use a lever base that way,  I assumed it was held to the stud with the claw end of the clip, and was drawing a blank on how the other end was attached.

Comment: Alex, this is awesomely done.  Your picture is a huge help in making sense of this.  And even then I had to stare at it for a minute to figure it out.

Comment: Is it a "legal" construction, or would connecting the window into the claw like that cause structural stress to the bricks?

Comment: @nick012000 I think TLG wouldn't use lever base for anything else than lever itself simply because it always comes pre-assembled so is considered as single item. So I doubt there is a question if this pictured assembly would be considered legal.

Comment: What a fantastic jury-rig!! Thank you for showing me this in detail!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, esp. if it is edited to include the part #/desc. _directly_ answering the original post.